# Link Paths disappears on re-call same tree function - D3 tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

I am able to draw tree structure with json data on initial load of the application.

Now my requirement is, on click of button I should be able to add more text/css to each nodes which is working fine.
I am actually using the same function used to draw tree initially, able to interchange data on trigger of button.

When I do so, on click the first level node (to expand to second level), first level paths disappears from g tag and selected node changes the position and lies in second level data.

Tired all possible ways, can anyone help to resolve this.

thanks in advance

Below is the tree function used

```
//To draw tree structure for the selected data
    drawTree: function() {
        var driverTree = this;
        var id = "#" + this.getView().byId("chartArea").sId;
        // ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
        var treeData = driverTree.treeModel.oData;
        var radius = 40;
        var width = $(id).width();
        var height = window.innerHeight;
        var maxLabel = 1500;
        var i = 0,
            duration = 450,
            root;

        var tree = d3.layout.tree()
            .size([height, width])
            .separation(function(a, b) {
                return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 2);
            });
        var margin = {
            top: 20,
            right: 120,
            bottom: 20,
            left: 120
        }
        var slider = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([1, 100])
            .range([1, 100])
            .clamp(true);
        var canvasWidth = radius * 2 + margin.left + margin.right,
            canvasHeight = radius * 2 + margin.top + margin.bottom;
        var color = d3.scale.category10();
        var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
            .projection(function(d) {
                return [d.y, d.x];
            });

        var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .value(function(d) {
                if (isNaN(parseFloat(d.value)))
                    return 0;
                else
                    return parseFloat(d.value);
            })
            .sort(null);
        // arc object
        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .outerRadius(40)
            .innerRadius(20);
        //var id = "#" + chartArea.sId;
        d3.select(id).select("svg").remove();
        driverTree.zoomListener = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([0.1, 3])
            .on("zoom", function(d) {
                zoomed(d);
            });
        var svgGroup = d3.select(id).append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("class", "tooltip")
            .call(driverTree.zoomListener);

        function zoomed(d) {
            if (driverTree.hoizMode)
                svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")rotate(90,50,50)");
            else
                svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
        }
        var svg = svgGroup.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + "," + (height / 2) / 2 + ") rotate(90,50,50)");

        root = treeData;
        root.x0 = height / 2;
        root.y0 = 0;

        var div = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip").style("opacity", "0");

        function collapse(d) {
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d._children.forEach(collapse);
                d.children = null;
            }
        }
        root.children.forEach(collapse);
        //update(root);
        //d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");
        var circumference_r = 35;

        function update(source) {

            var levelWidth = [1];
            var childCount = function(level, n) {

                if (n.children && n.children.length > 0) {
                    if (levelWidth.length <= level + 1) levelWidth.push(0);

                    levelWidth[level + 1] += n.children.length;
                    n.children.forEach(function(d) {
                        childCount(level + 1, d);
                    });
                }
            };
            childCount(0, root);
            var newHeight = d3.max(levelWidth) * 263.6; // 25 pixels per line  
            tree = tree.size([newHeight, window.innerHeight]);
            // Compute the new tree layout.
            var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
                links = tree.links(nodes);
            // Normalize for fixed-depth.
            nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                d.y = d.depth * 180;
            });

            // Update the nodesâ€¦
            var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
                .data(nodes, function(d) {
                    return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
                });
            // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
            var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                .attr("id", function(d) {
                    return "id" + d.title;
                })
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    if (driverTree.hoizMode)
                        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ") rotate(-90)";
                    else
                        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ") rotate(0)";
                })
                .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                    mouseover(d);
                })
                .on("mousemove", function(d) {
                    mousemove(d);
                })
                .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                    mouseout(d);
                });
            if (driverTree.editTree) {
                nodeEnter.append("rect")
                    .attr("id", "hideButton")
                    .attr("width", function(d) {
                        if (d.id != "NODE1") return "40px";
                    })
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                        if (d.id != "NODE1") return "translate(-40,-70)";
                    })
                    .attr("rx", "5")
                    .attr("ry", "5")
                    .attr("height", function(d) {
                        if (d.id != "NODE1") return "25px";
                    })
                    .style("stroke", "#999faa")
                    .style("stroke-width", "2px")
                    .style("fill", function(d) {
                        if (d.isHidden) return "#000f2b";
                        else return "#8E94A1";
                    })
                    .on("click", function(d) {
                        d.isHidden = !d.isHidden;
                        if (d.isHidden) return this.style.fill = "#000f2b";
                        else return this.style.fill = "#8E94A1";
                    });

                nodeEnter.append("text")
                    .attr("id", "hideText")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(-31,-54)")
                    .style("fill", "#eee")
                    .text(function(d) {
                        if (d.id != "NODE1") return "Hide";
                    })
                    .on("click", function(d) {
                        d.isHidden = !d.isHidden;
                        if (d.isHidden) return d3.select(this.parentNode).select("rect").style("fill", "#000f2b");
                        else return d3.select(this.parentNode).select("rect").style("fill", "#8E94A1");
                    });
            }
            nodeEnter.append("circle")
                .attr("r", "40")
                .on("click", click);
            nodeEnter.append("text")
                .attr("id", function(d) {
                    return "ct" + d.title;
                })
                .attr("x", "-8")
                .attr("y", "4")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return brevoVDT.util.Formatter.amountToMillions(d.value);
                })
                .on("click", click);
            nodeEnter.append("text")
                .attr("transform", "translate(55,-10)")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return "Org Value - " + brevoVDT.util.Formatter.amountToMillions(d.value_org);
                })
            nodeEnter.append("text")
                .attr("id", function(d) {
                    return "cv" + d.title;
                })
                .attr("transform", "translate(55,5)")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return "Currenet Value - " + brevoVDT.util.Formatter.amountToMillions(d.value);
                })
            nodeEnter.append("text")
                .attr("id", function(d) {
                    return "dv" + d.title;
                })
                .attr("transform", "translate(55,20)")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return "Difference  " + brevoVDT.util.Formatter.amountToMillions(parseFloat(d.value_org) - parseFloat(d.value));
                })
                .style("fill", function(d) {
                    var value = parseFloat(d.value_org) - parseFloat(d.value);
                    if (value > 0) return "green";
                    else if (value < 0) return "red";
                    else return "black";
                })
                /*nodeEnter.append("text")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(-50,58)")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
                    .text(function(d) {
                        return d.title;
                    })*/
            nodeEnter.append("rect")
                .attr("width", "130px")
                .attr("transform", "translate(48,-25)")
                .attr("height", "50px")
                .attr("rx", "15")
                .attr("ry", "15")
                .style("fill", "rgba(238, 238, 238, 0)")
                .style("opacity", "0.9")
                .style("stroke",
                    function(d) {
                        if (d.children == null && d._children == null)
                            return "black";
                        else
                            return "orange";
                    })
                .style("stroke-width", "2");
            nodeEnter.append("g").attr("class", "slicers");
            nodeEnter.append("g").attr("class", "lines");
            var pieNodes = nodeEnter.select(".slicers").selectAll("path")
                .data(function(d, i) {
                    if (d.id == "NODE1") var value = 0;
                    else var value = d.parent.value;
                    value = value == 0 ? 1 : value;
                    return pie([d, {
                        value: value
                    }]);
                })
                .enter()
                .append("svg:path")
                .attr("class", "slice")
                .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                    return color(i);
                })
                .each(function(d) {
                    d;
                })
                .attr('d', arc)

            //toolbar
            function mouseover(d) {
                div.transition()
                    .duration(500)
                    .style("opacity", 0.9)
                    .style("display", "block");
            }

            function mousemove(d) {
                var name = d.name.length > 13 ? d.name.slice("0", "13") : d.name;
                div.html("<b>" + d.title + "</b><table>" +
                    "<tr><td>" + name + ":</td><td>" + parseFloat(d.value).toFixed(1) + "</td></tr></table>")

                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 50) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 0) + "px");
            }

            function mouseout(d) {
                div.transition()
                    .duration(500)
                    .style("display", "none");

            }
            // Transition nodes to their new position.
            var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    if (driverTree.hoizMode)
                        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ") rotate(-90)";
                    else
                        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ") rotate(0)";
                });
            nodeUpdate.select("circle");
            nodeUpdate.select("text");
            nodeUpdate.select("rect");
            nodeUpdate.select("foreignObject");
            // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
            var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    if (driverTree.hoizMode)
                        return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ") rotate(-90)";
                    else
                        return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ") rotate(0)";
                })
                .remove();
            nodeExit.select("circle");
            nodeExit.select("text");
            nodeExit.select("rect");
            nodeExit.select("foreignObject");
            // Update the linksâ€¦
            var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
                .data(links, function(d) {
                    return d.target.id;
                });
            // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
            link.enter().insert("path", "g")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("d", function(d) {
                    var o = {
                        x: source.x0,
                        y: source.y0
                    };
                    return diagonal({
                        source: o,
                        target: o
                    });
                });
            // Transition links to their new position.
            link.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("d", diagonal);
            // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
            link.exit().transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("d", function(d) {
                    var o = {
                        x: source.x,
                        y: source.y + 100
                    };
                    return diagonal({
                        source: o,
                        target: o
                    });
                })
                .remove();
            // Stash the old positions for transition.
            nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                d.x0 = d.x;
                d.y0 = d.y;
            });
        }
        // Function to center node when clicked/dropped so node doesn't get lost when collapsing/moving with large amount of children.
        function centerNode(source) {
            var scale = driverTree.zoomListener.scale();
            var x = -source.y0;
            var y = -source.x0;
            if (driverTree.hoizMode) {
                d3.select("g").transition()
                    .duration(1)
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + "," + (height / 2) / 2 + ")scale(" + scale + ")rotate(90,50,50)");
                driverTree.zoomListener.translate([width, (height / 2) / 2]);
            } else {
                d3.select("g").transition()
                    .duration(1)
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + height / 2 + "," + -width / 2 + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
                driverTree.zoomListener.translate([height / 2, -width / 2]);
            }
            driverTree.zoomListener.scale(scale);

        }

        // Toggle children on click.
        function click(d) {
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d.children = null;
            } else {
                d.children = d._children;
                d._children = null;
            }
            update(d);
            centerNode(d)
        }

        function collapse(d) {
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d._children.forEach(collapse);
                d.children = null;
            }
        }

        update(root);
        centerNode(root);
```

Below is my edit function code

```
// To make the tree editable
    handleEdit: function(evt) {
        var that = this;
        this.editTree = !this.editTree;
        this.treeModel.oData.x = 0;
        this.treeModel.oData.y = 0;
        this.treeModel.oData.x0 = 0;
        this.treeModel.oData.y0 = 0;
        this.treeModel.oData.children.forEach(function(d){
            d.x = 0; d.y = 0; d.x0 = 0; d.y0 = 0;
            var children = (d._children == undefined ? d.children : d._children );
            children.forEach(function(a){
                a.x = 0; a.y = 0; a.x0 = 0; a.y0 = 0;
            });
        });
        this.drawTree();

    },
```

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: have provided my two function codes